# Why are my various CASE WHEN functions returning the same values?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Im trying to write a query that returns a count depending on the value of a feedback field that ranges from 0-5 (0 meaning that it was not rated).

I want:

- Count of all rows ( anything rated 1 or greater)
- Count of all rows rated as 1 (anything = 1)
- And all rows rated as 1 and also is the first iteration of a given task (anything rated =1 and iteration = 0)

I have written this query but I am getting the same value for all counts:

```sql
select
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M') as Month,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN rate > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN rate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Rated_1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN client_feedback = 1 AND index = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS first_iteration_rated_1
from tablexxx
where created_at between date('2022-04-01') and date('2022-10-01')
GROUP BY Month
```

Comment: Why are you `COUNT`ing instead of `SUM`ing? `SUM`s treat 0s and 1s differently, `COUNT` will treat 0 and 1 the same (although it will treat null differently).

Comment: Your comment says *anything rated 1 or greater*, but your code `WHEN rate > 0 ` says *anything rated **0** or greater*. Which is it?

Comment: @Bohemian I think you're confused. Assuming integers, `> 0` is the same as `>= 1` which is "anything rated 1 or greater"

Comment: Just replacing count with sum should provide the expected results.

Comment: @EdmCoff how do you know if rate is an integer?

Comment: @Bohemian You're right, I don't. Sorry. It is an assumption. I think it's correct based on OP wording, but I should have only said: `> 0` doesn't mean "anything rated 0 or greater."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`.

`Count()` will count up regardless of the value being 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

you can have two approaches:

method 1: use NULL in else part of the CASE

```
select
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M') as Month,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN rate > 0 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN rate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Rated_1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN client_feedback = 1 AND index = 0 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS first_iteration_rated_1
from tablexxx
where created_at between date('2022-04-01') and date('2022-10-01')
GROUP BY Month
```

method 2: use sum instead of count

```
select
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M') as Month,
  SUM(CASE WHEN rate > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Rated_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN client_feedback = 1 AND index = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS first_iteration_rated_1
from tablexxx
where created_at between date('2022-04-01') and date('2022-10-01')
GROUP BY Month
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should have realised this, works perfectly